# Should I always safely remove a bootable USB before unplugging it?

Tags: boot, usb

I have dowloaded the ISO of a Linux distribution called Manjaro. I flashed the ISO to USB in order to boot and install it later. My USB became bootable and read-only.

I can format it (with or without zeroes) and make it removable again, but the data in this bootable USB is write-protected. After that, I forgot to click Safely Remove before unplugging it from my PC. I am afraid this act could cause a problem to the OS flashed on USB, or any data corruption/loss or something else.

Comment: It can cause issues and you should always Safely Eject. But it does not always cause problems so you should be OK here

Comment: After I boot an OS from USB and get the jobs done, when i shut down the system and leave the live session , it doesnt properly unmount device. I often see messages after i leave the live session of an linux distro flashed on USB like cant unmount, it is busy

Comment: I always use the safely remove feature. I have a bricked a few usb flash drives by not doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have fast removal for USB devices enabled in your operating system, you should always use the safe removal option.  Improper unplugging the USB drive can still cause damage, even if you do not think any data is being written or read.  The option is there for a reason.

Comment: And with read-only ( write-protected) data on USB?

Comment: @RobertZaku It can still damage the drive.

Comment: @RobertZaku can it though? Can you provide a pointer to related information?

Answer (score 0):

A read-only filesystem in a USB drive should have no problems with unsafe removal.

Safe removal umounts the disk and ejects it. The command ´eject´ might trigger the deregistration from the USB bus and even a shutdown of the drive´s internal hardware (the actual response depends on the hardware). That lets the kernel know that the device is no longer available, in advance.

If you simply unplug the drive, the kernel will deregister the device on its own, and mount will react to a missing drive. That's not ideal, but if there was not data to be written, you should have no problems.